# update PDF file to mysql BLOB You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I upload a file PDF into MySQL database but the update methode donc work it keep give me an error, i tried to fix it but cant work 
thats the methode,

```
public void updateProjet(String location,String img) throws Exception
              {
                   // Créer une connexion JDBC Oracle sur la Base de Données 
       .. ici connection ..

           String cad = "update  projet set NomProjet='"+this.getnom_projet()+
             "', DateDeb='"+this.getdd()+ "', DateFin='"+this.getdf()+
             "', iduser='"+this.getid()+ "',IdProjet='"+this.getnprojet()+
           "',?,? where idpro='"+this.getidpro()+"'";
        PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(cad);
        pStmt.setString(1, img);

        File fichier = new File(location);
        FileInputStream io = new FileInputStream(fichier);
        pStmt.setBinaryStream(2,  (InputStream)io,(int)fichier.length());

        pStmt.executeUpdate();
              }
```

the error is :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Exercices2_corrige_2.pdf',_binary'%PDF-1.4
%Çì�¢
5 0 obj
<</Length 6 0 R/Filter' at line 1
```

Please Help and thanks a lot,

Comment: You have an [sql injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Fix it now, before someone trashes your server for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't set the column name for the parameterized value of your statement. 
You would have to use something like : 
`columnName=?` 
where you use the `?`alone.

And as precised in the comment it is a far more better practice to use parametrized parameter for all your parameter request to prevent SQL Injection holes.

Comment: thats good, i forget the names, 6hours of work and i can't keep going thanks a lot

Comment: But it is truly an important to thing to use parametrized statements

Comment: Have a look at : http://bobby-tables.com/java.html but basically use `?` like you did for two parameters instead of adding Strings to create your query.

Comment: thats simple, it's juste make query use ? in every time and did that fix the sql injection ?